# Can I change the style to none by using getatrribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

recently I am creating a drag and drop game.
When the items are dropped correctly, I want to set the original value to none.

```js
function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var dropdata = ev.target.getAttribute("drop-id")
  if (data == dropdata){
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
   a = ev.target.getAttribute("drop-id");
   a.style.display = "none";}
}
```

```css
.App{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.App .Box{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.App .Box .Boxes{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.AM {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    width: 90%;
}

.Example {
    border-style: Dashed;
    border-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
}

.DB{
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
        <div class = "App">
            <div class = "Box">
                <div class "Boxes">
                    <div class = "AM">This is A</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is B</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is C</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is D</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is E</div>
                </div>

                <div class = "Boxes">       
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "1">Drop here to match</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "2">Drop here to match</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "3">Drop here to match</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "4">Drop here to match</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "5">Drop here to match</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class = "Boxes">
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "1">A</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "2">B</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "3">C</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "4">D</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "5">E/div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to divisible the "Drop here to match" after dropping the items.
I used `getAttribute()` to get the corresponding ID. However, it seems it cannot turn it to `none`.
Is there any way to turn to `display : none` or `visibility : hidden` by using `getAttribute()`?
Thank you

Comment: `a` is a string and strings don't have a `.style` property.

Comment: `drop-id` is not a valid attribute in HTML. Use a `data-*` attribute for this type of custom attributes: `data-drop-id` -> [Using data attributes - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Are you trying to remove the attribute drop-id? (and as @Andreas has pointed out change that to have data- in front).

Comment: @AHaworth I am trying to remove the sentence "Drop here to match" in the div

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the target, then change Drop function to this:

```
function drop(ev) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var dropdata = ev.target.getAttribute("drop-id")
    if (data == dropdata){
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
        ev.target.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var dropdata = ev.target.getAttribute("drop-id")

  if (data == dropdata){
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
   a = ev.target.getAttribute("drop-id");
   
   ev.target.style.display = "none";
   document.getElementsByClassName('AM')[a - 1].style.display = "none";
   
}
}
```

```css
.App{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.App .Box{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.App .Box .Boxes{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.AM {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    width: 90%;
}

.Example {
    border-style: Dashed;
    border-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
}

.DB{
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "App">
            <div class = "Box">
                <div class "Boxes">
                    <div class = "AM">This is A</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is B</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is C</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is D</div>
                    <div class = "AM">This is E</div>
                </div>

                <div class = "Boxes">       
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "1">Drop here to match A</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "2">Drop here to match B</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "3">Drop here to match C</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "4">Drop here to match D</div>
                <div class = "Example" ondrop = "drop(event)" ondragover = "allowDrop(event)" drop-id = "5">Drop here to match E</div>
                </div>
                
                <div class = "Boxes">
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "1">A</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "2">B</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "3">C</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "4">D</div>
                <div class = "DB" draggable = "true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" id = "5">E</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```